# Solution for error ClassDefNotFound in Java

Tags: java, makefile, noclassdeffounderror

I have five class files `Servant.class, Server.class, Client.class, TransferRequest.class and TransferResponse.class`. My `Makefile` is at the below. I have this error for any of my class file:

Error occurred during initialization of VM

```
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'TransferRequest.class' failed
```

How can I cope with this error? I really tried all solutions which was written here such changing path or sth. This `makefile` is also 5th or 6 th one. The other well known makefiles gave same error too. I am on Windows machine I use cygwin.

Makefile:

```
JAVAC=javac
sources = $(wildcard *.java)
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all: $(classes)

clean :
    rm -f *.class

%.class : %.java
    $(JAVAC) $<
```

Comment: Add a makefile tag too - could be useful.

Comment: Are you really required to use Make? If not, use a Java build tool such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).

Comment: @jesper why should this not work?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I didn't say it won't work, but there are better tools than Make and that almost everybody uses for Java projects.

Comment: @Jesper make is a fine tool - the only problem is that javac is so expensive to start that the "invoke pr file" approach make prefers is too slow.  I guess there was a reason javac was designed to be able to compile many files for each invocation.  Anyway - from the snippet shown I would venture that it is not Makes fault the compiler does not work.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, the problem is most likely not cause by Make, if `java.lang.Object` cannot be found then most likely the user's JDK is not installed correctly.

Comment: I use cygwin. I have to compile it with makefile because it my assignment and I have to send Makefile too. Of course I have already run it. But I should do it by makefile too.

Answer (score 0):

Add a classpath (with the -cp) option to your javac.

```
JAVAC=javac -cp "$CLASSPATH"
```

Or you could change

```
$(JAVAC) $<
```

to add the classpath

```
$(JAVAC) -cp "$CLASSPATH" $<
```

Comment: What is the class path. Is it a dir where javac.exe locateed?

Comment: No. It's the PATH that javac searches for classes. If javac can't find "java/lang/Object" then your classpath is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with javac.  Either something is missing from your make file or your java installation is broken.

Find out if you can compile a file by hand with javac to narrow it down.

Comment: I can't compile it with javac command. it returns same error.

Comment: Then your JDK installation is broken.  Reinstall the JDK and see if it helps.  Remember to either give the full path to `javac` or add the installation directory to your `%PATH%` variable.